# Check when a modal is closed?

Tags: zurb-foundation

When my modal is closed I wish to do something.

I've checked the docs, and they suggest:

```
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
        var modal = $(this);
    });
```

Is there a way to target a specific modal, as I have several on my page?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one modal active at a time. To get the model when its closed, it uses the **close.fndtn.closed** event.

```
$(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {  
  var modal = $(this);
});
```

You should be able to use the ID of the model.

```
<div id="myModal1" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>Modal one</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>Modal two</div>

$(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {  
  var modal = $(this);
  if (modal.attr('id') == 'myModal2') {
    //do something here.
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this so I'm not sure that is the correct way to get the id. It could also be **modal.id**